# Windows wireless bridge with NAT

Tags: networking, nat, wireless-bridge

Here is my setup: I have a robot that I want to access remotely, but there is no wired connection. *If* the robot was configured to DHCP, I think could bridge the wired and wireless connections on a laptop so that the robot could grab an IP and be usable from the network.

However, the robot is set to a static IP (192.168.0.1) and I can't change it. Is it possible for me to set the laptop's wired connection to 192.168.0.2, bridge it with the wireless connection, and somehow route the traffic from the wireless interface to the robot? Could the robot would then have a public IP address accessible from the network? Sounds a lot like NAT, but I have no idea how to configure this on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool I was looking for was Microsoft's [netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754535%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which supports NAT routing. Unfortunately, the routing context is only available in Windows Server, not 7, so I gave up. See [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/30c1affa-cc6b-4eeb-9377-7600cc3f333a/nat-in-windows7) for more information.

Comment: Yes, the "you have the wrong Windows license" problem is incredibly frustrating. It is the reason I never use Windows by choice.